# How to launch the PlatLogoActivity

Tags: android

How do I launch `com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity` from my app (`com.gigabyte568.gbrom`)?

Codes that I have tried:

**Code 1:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.internal", "com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Code 2:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.internal.app", "com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Code 3:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android", "com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

**Code 4 (I got the "android" package name when I extracted the framework-res.apk):**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("android", "com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But `Code 1`, `Code 2`, `Code 3` and `Code 4` made my app crash. How do I do this?

Comment: Please provide your error logs for each of your code. I'm not sure, but if I remember well, you could have something to do with the manifest in order to authorize this call.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your manifest file the Activity

```
<activity android:name="com.android.internal.app.PlatLogoActivity" />
```

to start the Activity use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActvity.this,GotoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

   <activity android:name="com.android.internal.app.GotoActivity" />
```

CurrentActvity.this  in which do u hace now

GotoActivity.class in which do u want to go

Answer (score 0):

In manifest file set:

```
<activity android:name="com.android.internal.app.PLATLOGOACTIVITY" />
```

make sure **PLATLOGOACTIVITY** is **capitalized**.

In your java file set:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.internal.app.PLATLOGOACTIVITY");
startActivity(intent);
```